# How to send value to state using react bootstrap FormControl dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, form-control

I am using [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) [FormControl](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/) dropdown. In this DD  I applied map function which iterates and provides the dropdown options.

I am not getting how to set the value of selected option. I tried to use `onChange` and `onSelect`. On change I called following line of code:
Below is simple example of drop which is used in Reactjs using React-Bootstrap:

```
export default class SignUp extends Component {
```

constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.register =this.register.bind(this);
this.handleChangeDate = this.handleChangeDate.bind(this);

this.state = {
 gender:'',
 genderCat: [],
}
handleChangeGender(){
  const name = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;
  console.log(name, value);
  this.setState({[name]: value});
  console.log(this.state);   
}

 componentDidMount() {
api to get gender => GetData('getGender').then( (result) => {
    this.setState({
      genderCat: result

      });
    // this.state.data = result.message_text;
    // console.log(data.message_text);
})    



 render() {
                <FormControl
                    name="gender"
                    componentClass="select"
                    placeholder="select"
                    onChange={this.handleChangeGender}
                  >

                      {
                        this.state.genderCat.map((data) =>
                        <option key={data.id} value={data.value}  > 
                         {data.name}</option>
                        )
                      } 
                        <FormControl.Feedback />
                    </FormControl>  
   }
  }
```

How to set state value here ? I am getting one step behind state value.Like for very first time if I select Male (coming from map function, its value is 1) then then in state its give null, but then onchange female its taking 1, now if I change to other then its takes 2 ( its value of female)

Comment: can you provide what you tried with onChange?

Comment: updated @eramit2010

Comment: I had done a change. @eramit2010

Comment: Can you try this?
onChange={e => {
   this.getSelectedVal(e.target.value);
}}

Comment: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined this is the new error in above code line no 2 @eramit2010

Comment: As I explain in my other comment there is no name in your FormControl.

Comment: Also `setState` wont immediately mutate `state`. So if you console `state` straight after `setState`, you might end up getting the previous state only.

Comment: How to set state using formControl options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you can't do it but here is a working example from documentation without validation and with a little bit change:

```
import React from "react";
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";

const genderList = [
  { id: 1, name: "male" },
  { id: 2, name: "female" },
  { id: 3, name: "other" }
];

// mimicing API request
const getGender = () =>
  new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(genderList);
    }, 1000)
  );

class FormExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    gender: "",
    genderCat: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getGender().then(data =>
        this.setState({ genderCat: data, gender: data[ 0 ].name }));
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  createOptions = () =>
    this.state.genderCat.length
      ? this.state.genderCat.map(data => (
          <option key={data.id} value={data.name}>
            {data.name}
          </option>
        ))
      : "";

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <p>
          Selected gender: <strong>{this.state.gender}</strong>
        </p>
        <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect">
          <ControlLabel>Select</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            name="gender"
            componentClass="select"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            {this.createOptions()}
          </FormControl>
        </FormGroup>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default FormExample;
```

Comment: This is how I implement options in map:` <FormControl componentClass="select" 
                                    placeholder="Gender" 
                                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        >
                          <option value="dummy"> Gender</option>
                          {
                            this.state.genderCat.map((data) =>
                            <option key={data.id} value={data.value}>{data.name} 
                         </option>
                            )
                          }

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Just edit your question with your whole code and try to explain a little bit more.

Comment: Why are you using getSelectedVal? You can set your state with the code I gave. You are holding your state as "value" key. You are using e.target.name in your code but there is not any name attached to your FormControl. Please give more details as much as possible. Like is that select options will hold gender in your state? Do you want to set state with this option?

Comment: yes it will hold gender in state.since there are many other input fields so I am setting the state and doing some manipulations using that.How can I set the state with this options? @devserkan

Comment: I've edited my answer. It simply changes the state as name value. Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/w7qqyn7545

Comment: Its working but now onchange state taking one step back value. like if male - 1 female - 2 and other is 3 then if I selected male for very first time then it take null but afte that if I select female then it taking 1 (one step back value)

Comment: Where is this happening? Please show us your whole code. If you don't, we can't help you. Edit your answer, post your whole code. I'm not a pro as well but if someone wants to help you they need to see the code.

Comment: On some research I also find that for accessing the selected option of select tag which is coming through map function, we need to use `ref` attribute in react

Comment: Yes we can use ref's if needed. But in your example we are setting state dynamically with [e.target.name] easily, hence ref is not needed. If you want to do this with ref's you will add `ref={ (node) => { this.genderForm = node; } }` to your FormControl and will set state like this: `this.setState({ [this.genderForm.props.name]: e.target.value });`

Comment: @devserkan ...how to set multiple values that's the requirement for me